# Implementing the action of $SO_{3}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{5}$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to make a visualization of the unique irreducible action of $SO_{3}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{5}$. Since it's described using spherical harmonics, what I did was write a function that takes a 5 vector and a parameter, and outputs the spherical harmonic correspondent to the 5 vector (using the standard basis of the harmonics) rotated according to the parameter. Then what I want is to take that output and get back a 5-vector correspondent to that function, so I need to calculate the inner product of that function with the basis spherical harmonics, which I did in the following function (in a really ugly way, I know):

```
action[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, t_] = {a, b, c, d, e}.Table[
SphericalHarmonicY[2, m, θ, ϕ + t], {m, -2, 2}];

realaction[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, t_] = {Integrate[
Conjugate[action[a, b, c, d, e, t]]*action[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]*
 Sin[θ], {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}], Integrate[
Conjugate[action[a, b, c, d, e, t]]*action[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]*
 Sin[θ], {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}], Integrate[
Conjugate[action[a, b, c, d, e, t]]*action[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]*
 Sin[θ], {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}], Integrate[
Conjugate[action[a, b, c, d, e, t]]*action[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]*
 Sin[θ], {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}], Integrate[
Conjugate[action[a, b, c, d, e, t]]*action[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]*
 Sin[θ], {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}]};
```

But Mathematica doesn't seem to stop evaluating when I try to run realaction on anything, despite the fact that when I use specific values, it works. As in, when I take the code for realaction and manually replace the values of a,b,c,d,e and t, then it calculates easily. I think it's got something to do with how it evaluates integrals, but I'm not sure how to tell Mathematica not to try to calculate the integral before it has actual values for the variables.

Comment: To keep it from evaluating until numeric values are provided, use `realaction[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, 
  e_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := ...`

Comment: thank you, that did the trick :)

Comment: huh, i made a mistake, it's not doing the trick. it's still trying to evaluate the integral symbolically before getting any values

Comment: now the first coordinate just outputs to:

4 \[Pi] action[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] Conjugate[action[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

when i try to calculate it for [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: Did you `Clear[realaction]` to remove the previous definition and use `SetDelayed ( := )` rather than `Set ( = )` in the definition of `realaction`? When I evaluate `realaction[1,0,0,0,0,0]` I get `{1,0,0,0,0}` Is that what you expect?